# Best way to write multiple or conditions on a object in JAVA

Tags: java

Is there an easier way to perform `||` and `&&` operations, maybe using Java 8?
As I have some other classes like `OrderSummaryService` and it has some more fields.

```
@Getters
@Setters
class Orders
{
    String id;
    String status;
    Items items;
    String orderDate;
    String createdBy;
    String updatedBy;
    Double amount;
}

@Getters
@Setters
class Items
{
    String itemId;
    String itemName;
    String amount;
    String quantity;
}


class OrderSummaryService
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Orders orders = orderRepository.getOrderDetails();
        if (orders.getStatus() != null || orders.getCreatedBy() != null
            || orders.getUpdatedBy() != null || orders.getAmount() != null
            || orders.getOrderDate() != null && orders.getItems() != null)
        {
            OrderDetail details = orderRepository.updateRepository();
            ItemDetail itemDetail = itemRepository.updateItem();

            // some service code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it may not be certain to all  what you want ,  rather than rely on the series of null checks would you explain what you expect the conditional to do?  And remember any answer is based on what someone considers easier for them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this to replace the chain of `||`s

```
Stream.of(orders.getStatus(), orders.getCreatedBy(), /*the others*/).anyMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

`anyMatch` is short-circuiting, works similar to a logical or

Comment: Where is `&& orders.getItems() != null`?

Comment: @saka1029 they would need to add it on the end, just like they would need to replace `/*the others*/`

Comment: I fail to see how this might be more expressive than the original code

Comment: @Michael I don't know how to express `(orderDate != null && items != null)` in your formula.  Do you know that `&&` takes precedence over `||`?

Comment: This would work, thanks. I can combine the above solution and your solution together

Comment: @saka1029 i do. `Stream.of(a, b, c, d).anyMatch(...) || (e && f)`

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much. I understand that.

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to be using the same logic in multiple places, I would add a method to the `Orders` class e.g.

```
public boolean isValidOrders() {
    return status != null || createdBy != null || updatedBy != null
            || amount != null || orderDate != null && items != null;
}
```